# How to use mathematica to evaluate measurement noise convariance?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Currently, I am using the arduino UNO to make a CanSat with acceleration sensor. However, the sensor is quite unstable and I am trying to use Kalman Filter to stabilize the reading.

However, how can i compute the measurement noise covariance with mathematica as a input to the Kalman algorithm?

Comment: It would be good to have sample data, optimally some code to show what you have already tried.